# pdfbox extract text by area units

Tags: pdfbox

I need to extract the address zip code from a pdf and I use the PDFTextStripperByArea class from pdfbox like in this example [ExtractTextByArea](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/ExtractTextByArea.java#L40). But what are the units of parameters in `Rectangle rect = new Rectangle( 10, 280, 275, 60 );` From where must measure and to what units? If they are pixels then it is not convenient to measure pdf page component positions in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The y-coordinates are java coordinates (y == 0 is top), not PDF coordinates (y == 0 is bottom).

The units are 1/72 inch which is identical to pixels when you render the PDF at 100%.

Comment: pdfbox-app PDFToImage allows to specify the dpi